# Detect click outside of view in SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that is showed when clicking on a button. Now I want to hide this view, when the user clicks somewhere else in the window. Is there a possibility to detect a click outside of a view without (!) adding an `.onTapGesture` to the parent view?

An example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("something here")
            MySpecialView()
        }
    }
    
}

struct MySpecialView: View {
    
    @State private var showed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("show") {
                self.showed = true
            }
            if showed == true {
                Text("this is a secret text")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How about adding a very large background that covers the whole screen, and add a `onTapGesture` on the background?

Comment: Personally I’m doubtful if this would be a good user experience, tapping on some random place in a view would change its content. I would use the button both to show and hide the text.

Comment: I would like to create something like a popover but unfortunately I didn't find a way to change the style of the `popover`-modifier, so this is the only way to achieve sth. like this.

Answer (score 0):

With some workarounds I found the following solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("something here")
            MySpecialView()
        }
    }
    
}

struct MySpecialView: View {
    
    @State private var showed = false
    @State private var clickHere = false
    
    // Popup-sizing
    @State private var popupHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private let popupWidth: CGFloat = 200
    private let popupPadding: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
            
        VStack {
            Button("show") {
                self.showed = true
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
            if showed == true {
                GeometryReader { reader in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("this is a secret window ;)")
                        Text("click around here and I will not close.")
                        Text("but click anywhere in the window, and I will go sleeping.")
                            
                        Button {
                            self.showed = false
                        } label: {
                            Text("close me")
                        }

                    }
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)  // only for the word wrap in the text
                    .frame(width: self.popupWidth)
                    .padding(self.popupPadding)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged({ val in
                        self.clickHere = true
                    }))
                    .background(.white)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.popupHeight = reader.size.height
                    }
                }
                .offset(x: -1 * self.popupWidth / 2.0 + 2*self.popupPadding)
                .offset(y: self.popupHeight)
            }
        })
        .onAppear(perform: {
            NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseUp]) { event in
                if self.clickHere == true {
                    self.clickHere = false
                } else {
                    self.showed = false
                }
                return event
            }
        })
    }
    
}
```

The only disadvantage is, that the view will not pop out of the window (I try to recreate a `DatePicker`)